# Routing with special character " : " in Angular2

Tags: angular, url, routes

My URL are like
abc.org/books/sort:created/direction:desc
abc.org/books/sort:mostviewed/direction:desc

abc.com/books/schools/sort:created/direction:desc
abc.com/books/schools/sort:mostviewed/direction:desc

I want my sort parameter to contains "created" or "mostviewed" but angular routerLink converts " : " to " %3A " and my links become

abc.org/books/sort%3Acreated/direction%3Adesc
abc.org/books/sort%3Amostviewed/direction%3Adesc

abc.com/books/schools/sort%3Acreated/direction%3Adesc
abc.com/books/schools/sort%3Amostviewed/direction%3Adesc

and "created" or "mostviewed" are not assigned to sort params.

How to I escape " : " both in routing & routerLink.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4895

You must extend encodeUri like this

```
encodeURIComponent(str) {
    return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function (c) {
        return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
    });
}
```